# Xamarin iOS UICollectionView.CellRegistration with generic, where is it?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I've been trying to figure out just exactly where the UICollectionView.CellRegistration<CellType,ItemType>.

I can see that there's a UICollectionViewCellRegistration.GetRegistration, but am not sure just how to call the Generic version or at least supply an ItemType for the GetRegistration one.

Answer (score 0):

quote from official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/api-changes/ios-13-20-2-14-0-0):

```
   public class UICollectionViewCellRegistration : Foundation.NSObject, Foundation.INSObjectProtocol, ObjCRuntime.INativeObject, System.IDisposable, System.IEquatable<Foundation.NSObject> {
        // constructors
        protected UICollectionViewCellRegistration (Foundation.NSObjectFlag t);
        protected UICollectionViewCellRegistration (IntPtr handle);
        // properties
        public virtual ObjCRuntime.Class CellClass { get; }
        public virtual UINib CellNib { get; }
        public System.Type CellType { get; }
        public override IntPtr ClassHandle { get; }
        public virtual UICollectionViewCellRegistrationConfigurationHandler ConfigurationHandler { get; }
        // methods
        public static UICollectionViewCellRegistration GetRegistration (ObjCRuntime.Class cellClass, UICollectionViewCellRegistrationConfigurationHandler configurationHandler);
        public static UICollectionViewCellRegistration GetRegistration (System.Type cellType, UICollectionViewCellRegistrationConfigurationHandler configurationHandler);
        public static UICollectionViewCellRegistration GetRegistration (UINib cellNib, UICollectionViewCellRegistrationConfigurationHandler configurationHandler);
    }
```

and

```
public sealed delegate UICollectionViewCellRegistrationConfigurationHandler : System.MulticastDelegate, System.ICloneable, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable {
    // constructors
    public UICollectionViewCellRegistrationConfigurationHandler (object object, IntPtr method);
    // methods
    public virtual System.IAsyncResult BeginInvoke (UICollectionViewCell cell, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath, Foundation.NSObject item, System.AsyncCallback callback, object object);
    public virtual void EndInvoke (System.IAsyncResult result);
    public virtual void Invoke (UICollectionViewCell cell, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath, Foundation.NSObject item);
}
```

for example:

```
        var c = UICollectionViewCellRegistration.GetRegistration(typeof(UICollectionViewListCell), (cell, index,item)=> { 
        
        });
```